# How to share content via deep link in a Teams app?

Tags: javascript, typescript, microsoft-teams

I am developing a small Teams app also using the Teams-SDK. I am currently looking for a way to share contents from within my app in Teams (either via a chat or teams).

I found two ways:

- Sharing on a website to a Team by using the provided code here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/share-to-teams
- Sharing to a chat by using the deep link: https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=

However, both ways do not work as needed. The first method won't work from within a Teams app but only on websites. I also copied the used url from the method and tried to use it by using the "deeplink" function of the SDK but no luck.
The second method does not fit my needs, because the button should create a draft with a curated text but no user pre-selected.

Comment: can you explain a bit more what you're trying to do, I'm still not clear. Do you want users to be able to click a link, and have it load your tab with specific content, for example?

Comment: @chrisB2021 -  Are you looking for a way to send some data/card/message from your custom application to Teams chat/channel?
Please elaborate on it.

Comment: Thanks four your replies. In my app, I want to present the users with some content, e.g. from SharePoint or other sources. The users should be able to share a link to the content by clicking a button. Then a window/tab should open, where the user only needs to select the recipient/ teams channel but the message text is already prefilled.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft Thank you very much. This is very helpful and a big leap in the direction of what I try to achieve. However, I want my Teams-App to require as little as possible permissions, and to my understanding I would need the delegated permission of the user to post in a Team or chat. Is it also possible to prefill an empty chat window with a chat message but the recipient bar is empty (draft)? And for teams a solution like the share-on-website functionality, where the user also does not have to give any api permission. Thank you!

Comment: @chrisB2021 - I think you can use delegated permissions also to post in Team or chat, if it is supported (Check in the documentation).

You can post messages in chat using Graph API to fill the chats.
You can implement outgoing Webhook if you want to send contents from Microsoft Teams to your Web Application.

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning to present/show the content in Tab for users. if yes, you can have buttons on that tab & on click on button on content, it will open a Task Module with prefilled data & you can implement search functionality/dropdown list to show list of recipient/teams. You can share the content with URL's to selected recipient/teams in channel or 1:1 chat. Doc links: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http